# Fullpage.js: How to automatically add the name of the next or previous section

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, sections

A question about the Fullpage plugin:
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

I was wondering if I could automatically add the name of the next or previous section to a button, based on the current section where you are.

I couldn't find it here:
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/callbacks.html

I already made an unhandy manual solution, but there might be a better automatic solution (a function or something like that) for which some more Javascript knowledge is needed than I have.

This is my (temporarily) solution, assuming that my section names are homepage, chairs, arm chairs and stools.

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
                if(index == 1){
            $('#moveSectionUp').html('stools');
            $('#moveSectionDown').html('chairs');
                }
                if(index == 2){
            $('#moveSectionUp').html('homepage');
            $('#moveSectionDown').html('arm chairs');
                }
```

and so on...

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
        var loadedSection = $(this);   
        var prev = loadedSection.prev();
        var next = loadedSection.next();

        var prevText = (prev.length) ? prev.attr('data-arrow-text') : '';

        var nextText = (next.length) ? next.attr('data-arrow-text') : '';

        console.log(nextText);

        $('#moveSectionUp').html(prevText);
        $('#moveSectionDown').html(nextText);
    }
});
```

And use the attribute `data-arrow-text` in each section to define the text you want to show for the arrow to move to that section:

```
<div class="section" data-arrow-text="Demo"></div>
```

[Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1066/)

Comment: Very nice! What I forgot to say: I use your plugin option continuousVertical. When reached the last section, the next section must be the first section. When reached the first section, the previous section must be the last section. How to make that work? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello Alvaro, I tried to make a version using Onleave, because Onleave reacts immediately when you navigate, afterload has a small delay (load time), what Onleave does not have. However, this example with Onleave is not working. Can you look at it? http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1121/

Comment: Because in onLeave $(this) won't be the loaded section but the var leavingSection as stated in the documentation. You will have to get the loaded section by its index instead.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the comment that is placed directly under Alvaros solution:

Question = How to make Alvaros above solution work with continuous scrolling pages (using the plugin option continuousVertical)?

Answer = Very simple by slightly modifying the codes from Alvaros solution. Here's an explanation:

Replace the last `''` at the end of the below lines with the section names of your last and first section respectively:

```
var prevText = (prev.length) ? prev.attr('data-arrow-text') : '';

var nextText = (next.length) ? next.attr('data-arrow-text') : '';
```

Assuming that in this case the name of the last section is 'Arm Chairs' and the name of the first section is 'Homepage', it becomes:

```
var prevText = (prev.length) ? prev.attr('data-arrow-text') : 'Arm chairs';

var nextText = (next.length) ? next.attr('data-arrow-text') : 'Homepage';
```

That's it!

However, it is also assumed that you literately do what Alvaro recommended above:

> "And use the attribute `data-arrow-text` in each section"